# Color Picker in PreferenceBundle

Tags: objective-c, plist, jailbreak, color-picker, theos

I found some codes to change the color of text, link ecc in an App.

Now I'd add a color picker (like in the below link) to change the color.

http://prntscr.com/4gkfz9

Someone know how to code it?

Thanks

Comment: simple, develop an own colour picker. where have you been stuck at?

Answer (score 1):

This could help !

[RSColorPicker](https://github.com/RSully/RSColorPicker)

[Color-Picker-for-iOS](https://github.com/hayashi311/Color-Picker-for-iOS)

Answer (score 0):

this is sample of color picker in iOS .use it  this  sample allow the selection of a color from RGB space .

https://github.com/InfinitApps/InfColorPicker